# Searching for multiple fields within an Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, lookup

I have multiple fields from a database that I would like to search for within an Excel Workbook. The result I am looking for is to have all the fields that WERE NOT found within the workbook be displayed in multiple rows/columns and the ones that WERE found to be discarded.

I am just looking for an easier way of searching for these fields rather then (Cntrl + F) and then searching every specific field. (I have over 500 fields in about 30 different tables that I would like to search throughout this mapping Excel Workbook).

If someone has an idea of how to go about doing this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pnuts the input will be 20-30 fields. These will all be searched in the entire Excel Workbook. The desired output would be the left over fields that were not found within that workbook. As of right now I am just searching the entire workbook 1 field at a time, if it's not there I am adding it to a column. I am just searching for an easier, less tedious way of doing this.

Comment: I have various tables with many fields(columns) inside these tables. My objective is to search through all of these tables and see which fields are mapped in this excel sheet I have. If they are not in this excel sheet I need to list them, so that they can be mapped. I'm sorry if this is not clear, but I appreciate the help.